# Is double compression less effective?

Tags: compression, gzip, tar

Let's say we have multiple packages stored as `.tar.gz` files and we want to combine them into one bundle. Everything I know about lossless file compression is that it attempts to find patterns in the data. From that, my intuition is that it would be able to find more patterns and therefore produce smaller bundle if I first decompress the packages into `.tar` files and then combine them into one `bundle.tar.gz`. Is my intuition correct? Or is it not worth the hassle and creating the bundle from the `.tar.gz` files directly would produce similar results?

I tested it with a random collection of txts (RFC 1-500 from https://www.rfc-editor.org/retrieve/bulk/) and compressing each of them individually and then creating the final `.tar.gz` from the compressed files yields a 15% bigger result, which supports my intuition but maybe not to an extent I expected.

```
total size of txts:                           5.6M
total size of individually compressed txts:   2.7M
size of .tar.gz from txts:                    1.4M
size of .tar.gz from compressed txts:         1.6M
```

I would like to understand more how it behaves in general.

Answer (score 0):

Compressing something with gzip that is already compressed will generally expand the data, but only by a very small amount, multiplying the size by about 1.0003.

The fact that you are getting a 15% benefit from decompressing the pieces and recompressing the bundle means that your pieces must be relatively small in order for gzip's 32K byte matching distance to find more matches and increase the compression by that much. (You did not say how many of these individually compressed texts there were.)

By the way, it is easy to combine several .tar files into a single .tar file. Each .tar file is terminated with 1024 zero bytes. Strip that from every .tar file except the last one, and concatenate them. Then you have one .tar file to compress.